# C# Value Computation with Principal, Number of Payment, Interest

Tags: c#, computation

I'm creating an auto calculation of payment. But I don't know the formula of it. When the calculate payment button is click, it will auto compute the principal, number of payments and interest then it will output on payment.

Please see the Screenshot [image]

```
// Example1 Computation
Principal 100000
Number of Payments 9
Interest 2
//Then when the calculate payment is click, execute
Payment 12251.54

// Example2 Computation
Principal 200000
Number of Payments 8
Interest 3.5
//Then when the calculate payment is click, execute
Payment 29095.33

// Example3 Computation
Principal 150000
Number of Payments 12
Interest 1.5
//Then when the calculate payment is click, execute
Payment 13752.00
```

Here's my string

```
String principal = txt_principal.Text;
String numberofPayments = txt_nop.Text;
String interestRate = txt_irpp.Text;


String payment = txt_payment.Text;
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: That doesn't fit this forum, because you're pretty much asking for a reverse engineer. Anyhow, give us some more values (there's more  than one function which could fit this output) - or if you have the function you're using in the button click, it could be helpful :)

Comment: Sir. I want what to know the computation why its 12251.54. Thank you sir :)

Comment: It could be payment*1.225154 . Or it could be payment + payment /number of payments + 19.32. There's many different computations which could achieve this. You need to give us more values, the button_click function if you have it, or upload an IDA disassembly of the file somewhere - otherwise, there's in fact an infinite number of different possibilities.

Comment: Sure sir... I'll add other computation. :D Thank you sir for being interested on my issues :_(

Comment: I need to go for a sec - try that in wolfram alpha :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with computing and everything to do with basic accounting/economics.

Comment: @A.Abramov Don’t call Stack Overflow a forum! We do not want to be a forum but a collection of high quality questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Excel can do this for you: `=PMT(0.02,9,100000)`

The formula is as follows:

```
Where:

PV = 100000 (principal)
RATE = 0.02 (interest)
NPER = 9 (payments)

PMT = -RATE * ( PV * Math.Pow(1+RATE,NPER)) / ((Math.Pow(1+RATE,NPER)-1));
```

So for your code:

```
double PV = double .Parse(txt_principal.Text);
double NPER = double .Parse(txt_nop.Text);
double RATE = double.Parse(txt_irpp.Text) / 100;

double PMT = -RATE * ( PV * Math.Pow(1+RATE,NPER)) / ((Math.Pow(1+RATE,NPER)-1));
txt_payment.Text = (-PMT).ToString();
```

Comment: Sir Sir How can I put the answer on the textbox of Payment? I have txt_payment and button is btn_calpayment :D

Comment: @truelogicINC The last line does it: `txt_payment.Text = (-PMT).ToString();`

Comment: Wow!!!! IT WORKS!!! :D Thank you sir :D :D :D :D :D :D :D

Comment: Sir @Rob can I ask another issue :)

Comment: @truelogicINC Better to open a new question in that case :)

Comment: Oh sir sure sir. Thank you :D I'll send it over the link here after I'm done. :D

Comment: Sir here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913198/loop-the-principal-interest-number-of-payments-and-payments-in-c-sharp

Comment: I just have to create another account to post a new. :( I hope you can help me sir. I'm doin' a simple project about this. :(

Comment: Sir help me sir please :( I can't go on to my next face. :( here's my new problem connected on my first question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933807/how-to-loop-the-principal-interest-number-of-payments-and-payments-in-c-sharp"

Comment: sir sir sir @Rob I need help :(